# Get angle between imageview and touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a image view with positions ( `x:138` and `y:107` ) which isn't in the center of the screen. Now I wan't to calculate the angle between these points and the horizontal line but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone tell me more about this?

Comment: It's called [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, where Start- and endpoint is the images positions.

```
Example:

CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(50, 100);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(100, 100);

float angleVal = (((atan2((endPoint.x - startPoint.x) , (endPoint.y - startPoint.y)))*180)/M_PI);
```